# Xcode project snapshot tries to make disk image?

Tags: xcode, snapshot

When Xcode makes it's auto-snapshots, prior to a global find-and-replace for instance, the snapshot is created without error.  When I select File -> Create Snapshot the machine chugs away for 10-15 minutes (this is posted without hyperbole), and then fails with an error message similar to:

```
**Unable to create a snapshot**
fatal: unable to stat 'Users/{me}/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache/f_00476e': No such file or directory
```

Yes, that's the cache file for my browser.  No, it's not explicitly included in my project.  How can I tell Xcode to not do this?  I am using the default Snapshot folder, which is

```
/Users/{me}/Documents/Development/KissQuest/Snapshots
```

PS -> I don't have the courage to test whether or not the Xcode--auto-generated snapshots are valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question for posterity.

For some reason, there was a .git and .gitK lurking in /users/{me};  I killed those and then git init in the project folder and voila, re-initialized and running git.

git init was not enough; I had to purge the folder tree of bad .gits.